# WebAudio panning not working with WebRTC

Tags: javascript, html, webrtc, web-audio-api, audio-panning

I'm trying to make sound panning work with audio got through WebRTC, but with the code below it's not outputting any sound at all. But when I do the same thing with my local audio MediaStream it works.

What could be the problem?

```
var AudioContext = window.AudioContext || window.webkitAudioContext
audioCtx = new AudioContext()
audioCtx.listener.setOrientation(0,0,-1,0,1,0)

var panner = audioCtx.createPanner()
panner.setOrientation(1,0,0)
panner.refDistance = 20
panner.coneInnerAngle = 360
panner.coneOuterAngle = 0
panner.panningModel = 'equalpower'

var source = audioCtx.createMediaStreamSource(peer.stream)
source.connect(panner)
panner.connect(audioCtx.destination)
```

Answer (score 1):

What browser are you using? There are browser bugs that prevent it from working in some versions. Try a Firefox Nightly build (https://nightly.mozilla.org/), we've fixed the WebAudio/WebRTC integration.

Comment: thanks! that's great that firefox fixed this issue, but unfortunately I need to use chrome and as I found out the issue isn't fixed in it yet :(